# Get current page term title to use in WP_Query

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query

I am trying to format a template page for a custom taxonomy and I'm having a hard time getting the term of the current page to use in the query. This is what I've tried so far:

```
<?php       
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $report = single_term_title();
        $report_type = strtolower($report);
        $temp = $wp_query; 
        $wp_query = null; 
        $args = array(
          'showposts'=> 5,
          'orderby'  => 'meta_value',
          'meta_key' => 'report_date',
          'order' => 'DESC',        
          'post_type'=> 'match_report',
          'report_type' => $report_type,
          'paged'    => $paged
        );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 

        $wp_query->query($args);            
        if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
        ?>
```

when I `echo $report_type` I still get an uppercase value. Is there another function that I should be using rather than `single_term_title()`?

Comment: showposts is deprecated use `posts_per_page`instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what [`single_term_title` does](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/general-template.php#L725) and check the queried object with [`get_queried_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object).

```
function single_tax_slug() {
  $term = get_queried_object();

  if ( !$term )
    return;

  if ( is_category() ) {
    $term_slug = $term->slug;
  } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
    $term_slug = $term->slug;
  } elseif ( is_tax() ) {
    $term_slug = $term->slug;
  }

  return $term_slug;
}
$slug = single_tax_slug();
var_dump($slug);
```

If you look at that code, it is basically the first few lines of `single_term_title`, simplified considerably, and  altered to get the slug.